# Per group, select first row and another which matches a condition

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have the following data.table:

```
x <- data.table(a = c(1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 7, 10, 9, 8),
                b = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))
```

And, after grouping by `b`, I want to select rows which:

- are the first row of the group
- have the highest `a` in the group

If a single row satisfies both conditions, it should only be selected once (the group will only contain one row).

Each of these selections is trivial:

```
x[, .SD[1], by = b]  # selects first row per group
#    b  a
# 1: 1  1
# 2: 2  2
# 3: 3 10

x[, .SD[which.max(a)], by = b]  # selects row with the highest 'a' in the group
#    b  a
# 1: 1  3
# 2: 2  7
# 3: 3 10
```

But I can't figure out how to do both at once (obviously `.SD[1 | which.max(a)]` doesn't work). I could perform them separately and then `rbindlist` the final result, but I'd like to know if there's a simpler way.

For clarity, in the case above, the expected output would be (different order is also acceptable):

```
   b  a
1: 1  1
2: 1  3
3: 2  2
4: 2  7
5: 3 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to concatenate the index 1 (for the first row) along with `which.max` -returns a numeric index as well, then take the `unique` of that (in case the same value 1 is returned by `which.max` and use that to subset the data.table (`.SD`)

```
x[, .SD[unique(c(1, which.max(a)))], by = b]
#   b  a
#1: 1  1
#2: 1  3
#3: 2  2
#4: 2  7
#5: 3 10
```

---

Or use `.I`

```
x[x[, .I[unique(c(1, which.max(a)))], by = b]$V1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(a = c(1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 7, 10, 9, 8),
                b = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))

x %>% group_by(b) %>% filter(row_number() == 1 | a == max(a))
```

**Output**

```
#   a  b
#1: 1  1
#2: 3  1
#3: 2  2
#4: 7  2
#5: 10 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have those two columns, just take the union of the two tables:

```
funion(
  x[, lapply(.SD, max), by=b],
  x[, lapply(.SD, first), by=b]
)
```

I guess max is more efficient than your which.max, since it is optimized (see `?GForce`).